# Мультипроцессорность

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу сохранять файл в отдельном процессе. Безопасно ли это ? Ведь не должно быть таких же проблем как с многопоточность, так ?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
    def update(self, request):
        uid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        Process(target=self.save_file, args=(uid, request)).start()
        return uid
```

Comment: Если несколько процессов будут одновременно писать в один фаил, будет каша.

Comment: У меня они только в один лог пишут. На продакшене не проверял, но на локалке все круто. :)

Comment: про какие проблемы с многопоточностью вы говорите? `logging` по умолчанию умеет с несколькими *потоками* работать. Но чтобы из нескольких *процессов* писать в один лог, то требуется дополнительная синхронизация. Посмотрите в документации [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes)

Comment: у вас вопрос: " можно ли писать в один лог-файл из нескольких процессов?" или что-то другое. Старайтесь писать более информативные заголовки—у вас больше 100 вопросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В один файл нельзя, например тут должно быть 2001 строк, а по факту 1850

```
import multiprocessing
file='1.tmp'
open(file, 'w').write('')

def write(c):
    for r in range(c):
        with open(file, 'a') as f:
            f.write('%s\n' % r)
    print('count {}, r {}'.format(c, r))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        pool.map(write, [1000]*2)

    print('len', len(list(open(file))))
```

out:

```
count 1000, r 999
count 1000, r 999
len 1850
```

Comment: А помимо записи в один файл, есть ограничения ? Например, запись в одну базу или что-то типа того ?

Comment: http://www.quizful.net/post/thread-synchronization-in-python